# PagedCollectionView equivalent in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Is there any equivalent class in .net 3.5 or 4.0 for WPF like PagedCollectionView in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't, as seen in the [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) class documentation there are only three derivative classes.

- System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
- System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView
- System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView

(*There are some more classes sub-class CollectionView but they are internal*)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't BUT You can grab it from here - https://silverlight.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Release/Silverlight4/Source/System.Windows.Data/PagedCollectionView/

You may need more relevant types (all in the same folder).