# Linq filtering causes property to not update view

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following property that I would like to use Linq to filter. This allows the binding in my view to update the UI just fine:

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList; }
}
```

These solutions were suggested in another post, but they don't allow the view to update:

```
get { return new ObservableCollection<Worker>(DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Where(w => w.Known != true)); }
```

and

```
get
{
    var workerList = DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Where(w => w.Known != true);
    return workerList.ToObservableCollection<Worker>();
}
```

`DataManager` is a Singleton class and `Data` is its instance. How can I use Linq filtering in this property without throwing off the UI updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't really "using LINQ filtering", if you're using `ObservableCollection` you can use a `PagedCollectionView` to add a filter to the collection.

```
        PagedCollectionView items = new PagedCollectionView(Workers);
        items.Filter = (o) => (o as Worker).Known != true;
```

Then bind to `items`.

The problem with LINQ is that it creates a new collection, and so it breaks bindings. It's still possible to use it, but it can be a bit tiresome. Let me know if the above isn't what you need, and I'll try to figure something else out. ;)

EDIT: `PagedCollectionView` is only available in Silverlight. **If you're using WPF**, then you can try something like this:

```
        ICollectionView items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Workers);
        items.Filter = (o) => (o as Worker).Known != true;
```

Also, I recommend [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) article on how to display data in WPF (including sorting, filtering and such).

Comment: Which `using`s do I need to use for `PagedCollectionView`? VS isn't giving me any suggestions when I try to resolve.

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Windows.Data` to your project.

Comment: That reference was already there. Where in the code should it go? I've tried making it a member and placing it in the constructor but it's still not working. Intellisense isn't picking up `PagedCollectionView` at all.

Comment: OK... perhaps a more basic question should be asked: what kind of project are you working with? Is this Silverlight or WPF? (You didn't indicate it in the tags nor your question...) WPF doesn't have `PagedCollectionView`, but there's a way around that as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881962/pagedcollectionview-equivalent-in-wpf

Comment: Also, WPF has OTHER classes that can do something very similar to a `PagedCollectionView` in Silverlight - namely there's the `ICollectionView` interface which has a `Filter` property.

Comment: I'm using WPF. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my original post. I'll look into `ICollectionView`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a possible way of getting an `ICollectionView` instance for you to work with. :)

Comment: After a quick Google search it looks like this is exactly what I need. `ICollectionView` looks much more flexible than using Linq in the property. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks for your help!